# Aunt travelling with a 2 year old but not the parents

Tags: passports, legal, minors

I have power of attorney for my 2 year old niece. She has been living with me since September. I would like to take her with me when I travel this summer and her parents are not terribly involved in her life.

Can I secure a passport without them and if yes, how?
If no, what do I need to do?

Comment: Her nationality?  yours?

Comment: "Can I secure a passport without them?" In many countries, you need to have sole custody to be able to get a passport for the child by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I will use the [Canadian recommendations](http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/children/consent-letter) -- when entering into a foreign country they are very unlikely to look up the laws of your particular home country so this is good as a general guideline. A few choice quotes, but you need to read the whole page:

> A consent letter is not a legal requirement in Canada, but it can simplify travel for Canadian children, as it may be requested by immigration authorities when entering or leaving a foreign country or by Canadian officials when re-entering Canada
>
> We recommend that you talk to a lawyer about the legal issues that apply to you and your children’s unique situation

Most importantly:

> We recommend that the letter be signed by every non-accompanying person or organization with the legal right to make major decisions for the child

So while the parents are not involved they have the legal right from what I understand (but you should know this much better) and if so, border guard might ask a consent letter from them. But, as said above: this isn't a legal requirement at least not in Canada.

However, I am just a random stranger on the Internet and I am not a lawyer (I do not even play one on television). I would look into adoption to simplify this situation ongoing.